# How to mock aws timestream for unit test on python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pytest, moto, amazon-timestream

I found on the net an example to test the aws timestream service; when I try to launch the test I get a NoRegionError

```
#test_timestream.py

import logging
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd 
import awswrangler as wr
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import awswrangler as wr

logging.getLogger("awswrangler").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def test_basic_scenario(timestream_database_and_table):
    name = timestream_database_and_table
    df = pd.DataFrame(
       {
        "time": [datetime.now(), datetime.now(), datetime.now()],
        "dim0": ["foo", "boo", "bar"],
        "dim1": [1, 2, 3],
        "measure": [1.0, 1.1, 1.2],
       }
   )
   rejected_records = wr.timestream.write(
        df=df,
        database=name,
        table=name,
        time_col="time",
        measure_col="measure",
        dimensions_cols=["dim0", "dim1"],
   )
   assert len(rejected_records) == 0
   df = wr.timestream.query(
        f"""
          SELECT
             1 as col_int,
             try_cast(now() as time) as col_time,
             TRUE as col_bool,
             current_date as col_date,
             'foo' as col_str,
             measure_value::double,
             measure_name,
             time
             FROM "{name}"."{name}"
             ORDER BY time
             DESC LIMIT 10
        """
   )
   assert df.shape == (3, 8)
```

**ERROR**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeawJ.png)

how can the problem be solved? Since even the "moto" library does not offer the mock of the aws service ?

Comment: create the `Mock`'s yourself?

Comment: I really have no idea how to do this

Comment: You can find an article on how to use Mock here: https://realpython.com/python-mock-library/

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the AWS DataWrangler example for Timestream:

https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.timestream.write.html

When you call the constructor, you can pass the boto3_session or it will use the default session:

```
boto3_session (boto3.Session(), optional) – Boto3 Session. The default boto3 Session will be used if boto3_session receive None.
```

You boto3 configs need to specify a default region or you need to declare in the boto3 session.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

my_config = Config(
    region_name = 'us-west-2',
    signature_version = 'v4',
    retries = {
        'max_attempts': 10,
        'mode': 'standard'
    }
)

client = boto3.client('kinesis', config=my_config)
```